# Получение ссылки на страницу друга с помощью Facebook SDK

Tags: objective-c, ios, facebooksdk

Здравствуйте. Использую такую конструкцию для получения информации о друзьях:

```
NSDictionary *params = @{@"fields" : id,name,picture.width(300).height(300)};
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/taggable_friends"                                                   parameters:params];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
}];
```

Но как можно получить ссылку на друга? Возможно ли это вообще?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Так просто `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://facebook.com/%@",friend_id]`

Comment: Если бы было так все просто... friend_id представляет из себя нечто такое: AaL68_2KcaUorOo44P7wq2dXi5lHJX1ajsQKLUwiWLgmpaBa7x5pE9Yuiw2wHFDPMYHpIWkuCVbXDhxcXDKgUnnh0NuSCmggrS8Cqb7yqqjDaA. Поэтому просто подставить id не получится.